# How to drop a connection with flask

Tags: python, flask

Say, I have this tiny flask app if the user has a valid token when he posts something I give him something else. When he doesn't I want to silently drop his connection. How do I do that?

Here's some sample code to help you visualize what I want to do

```
@app.route("/do_action", methods=('POST',))
def do_action():
    if request.form['TOKEN'] not in valid_tokens:
        drop_connection()  # how?
    else:
        return get_action_result()
```

To be clear, I don't want to **throw an error** or **politely close the connection** I want to just drop the user request, let him hit the timeout.

Comment: Return something ?? This is what you can do with `WSGI`

Comment: The connection is opened already when you receive the request. You can't reject it any more. As soon as you are leaving the handler function Flask will close the connection properlybut not before sending an HTTP response. So, your only option would be to sleep until the request times out. That of cause requires a WSGI server that can handle left open connections well.

Answer (score -1):

if you have logout method implemented in your application, You can direct the user to logout return redirect("url for logout")